# Why aren't my pending changes being shown in RTC?

Tags: java, rtc

Scenario: I've just connected to a stream, and created a new repository workspace. I loaded the 2 components of it, and modified some code. If i open the Pending Changes view, i can't see any pending changes there (and my "show full view" is selected, so I should be seeing both the incoming, outgoing and suspended change sets).

My files are saved and i can obviously see the changes in the files, but no pending changes appear in the pending changes view.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For your changes to be displayed in the "Pending Change Views", you need to:

- either refresh your package explorer (i.e. an Eclipse-related view)
- or click on the little arrow next to the "refresh" button on your "Pending Changes" view and select:

  - refresh Sandbox and Remote Changes
  - or "refresh Sandbox"

[image: refresh sandbox]

(I tend to prefer the second method, because it allows me to chose what part of the -- potentially huge -- sandbox I need to refresh)

Comment: This is only necessary if the user modified code outside of Eclipse. Another alternative is to find the files in the Navigator or Package Explorer views and run an (Eclipse) refresh from there.

Comment: @ehughes: agreed. It will also allow you to chose what part of the Sandbox you need to refresh.

Answer (score 1):

I tried @VonC's suggestions which were helpful to my understanding, but they didn't work for me.

To get my changes to display in the Pending Changes view, I had to right click on the stream in the Team Artifacts view, Log Out, and then log back in.