# Checking for Out of Sync Folders

Tags: rational-team-concert

Every day when I start my Visual Studio, my RTC (Rational Team Concert) starts with a lengthy process of 'Checking for Out Of Sync Folders'.

I am not sure what is causing this and can some one help how to remedy the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [mentioned here](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/67602/how-to-handle-project-out-of-sync)

this error message should be improved. It should say something like:
"Files in your sandbox are out of sync with your repository workspace".

The [official documentation](https://jazz.net/help-dev/clm/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.team.scm.doc%2Ftopics%2Ft_scm_sync.html) includes:

> **A sandbox and repository workspace can become out-of-sync when a network failure or manual cancelation interrupts an update operation**.
>   When this happens, the next attempt to perform an operation (such as check in, accept, suspend, or resume) that updates both a sandbox and repository workspace generates a warning that the sandbox and repository workspace are out-of-sync.

[image: https://jazz.net/library/content/articles/rtc/2.0/source-control-load/images/outofsync.png]

<sup>(Image from "[Loading Content from a Jazz Source Control Repository in Rational Team Concert 2.0, 3.0 and 3.0.1](https://jazz.net/library/article/192)")</sup>

> If any of the out-of-sync projects contain unresolved local changes in the sandbox, by default, the reload operation preserves these changes

As [I advised here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9804066/6309), if you don't have any pending changes, you can

- try first a "refresh sandbox".  Then close everything, re-open Visual Studio and check you don't have any more "checking out" step.
- If the first workaround is not enough, "reload projects out of sync". (close and restart to see if the issue persists)

Comment: Yes. But it is taking hours together to do any of the recommended steps too. That is what causing a grave concern.

Comment: @DeepakVasudevan The goal is to test with: a Visual Studio only loading *one* project: try and synchronize that one projet (refresh or reload), just to see if the issue persists after closing and re-opening Visual Studio.

Comment: I have a solution file with 3 or 4 projects. You want me to open the individual .csproj file and see if that works out?

Comment: @DeepakVasudevan I just want you to test the refresh or reload, as long as it does not take you hours ;)